C# MVVM WPF TreeView with checkbox don't populate
My issue is that when i tried to create dynamically a TreeView with checkbox, but the TreeView is empty.
After some research i tried this :
Here is my treeview in XAML
<TreeView x:Name="TrwDonneesXml"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"
                                  Height="420" 
                                  Width="500" 
                                  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                                  Background="LightGray"
                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Root, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  IsEnabled="True">
                            <TreeView.Resources>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type models:CheckableItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childrens, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <!--These elements are bound to a CheckableItem object.-->
                                        <CheckBox Focusable="False"
                                                  Content="{Binding Name}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                   Margin="2,0"/>-->
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeView.Resources>
                        </TreeView>

Here is my ViewModel

namespace AsurEnvironnement.SynchronisationModule.ViewModels
{
    public class Synchronisation2UserControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
[...]
public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Root = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();
                ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> rootAChildrens = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();
[...]
               public override async Task InitializeStepAsync()
        {

            try
            {
                ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> rootAChildrens = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();
                ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> rootBChildrens = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();

                CheckableItem rootA = new CheckableItem() { Name = "RootA" };
                CheckableItem childrenA1 = new CheckableItem() { Name = "ChildrenA1" };
                CheckableItem childrenA2 = new CheckableItem() { Name = "ChildrenA2" };
                rootAChildrens.Add(childrenA1);
                rootAChildrens.Add(childrenA2);
                rootA.Childrens = rootAChildrens;

                CheckableItem rootB = new CheckableItem() { Name = "RootB" };
                CheckableItem childrenB1 = new CheckableItem() { Name = "ChildrenB1" };
                rootBChildrens.Add(childrenB1);
                rootB.Childrens = rootBChildrens;

                CheckableItem rootC = new CheckableItem() { Name = "RootC" };

                Root.Add(rootA);
                Root.Add(rootB);
                Root.Add(rootC);

                [...]
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ProcessSnackBar(ex.Message);
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                [...]
            }
        }
[...]
}

Here is my Model
namespace AsurEnvironnement.SynchronisationModule.Models
{
    public class CheckableItem : DataModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool? _isChecked;
        public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Childrens;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }

            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                foreach(CheckableItem children in Childrens)
                {
                    children.IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

I tried to check with Console.WriteLine(TrwDonneesXml.HasItems); to see if the data exist but can't be seen but the result is false so i checked in debug mode TrwDonneesXml.ItemsSource is null.
But i realy don't understand why.

I think your _isChecked "setter" might be recursing; and why always set it to "true" when "value" could be anything; and "tramping" nulls is pointless when a "false" substitute will do.

Don't set the Binding.Mode of a binding that targets the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property to BindingMode.TwoWay. The ItemsControl wil never ever change that value. It must stay OneWay. You can even push it further. Because you use an ObservableCollection as a binding source, you can set the Binding.Mode to BindingMode.OneTime. This yields the best performance. Because you always modify the source collection instead of replacing it, in this context the source collection property should also be defined as a read-only property to get compiler support to avoid bugs.

The Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger is already set to UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged by default. Better don't write redundant code to improve readability.

Note that your IsChecked property is recursive down to the leaf nodes. To improve the performance, you should enable UI virtualization on the TreeView: How to: Improve the Performance of a TreeView. And IsChecked must raise the PropertyChanged event.

@GerrySchmitz, yes i changed 'true" to "value" that was a mistake.

@BionicCode, about raise PropertyChanged, what does it change and how can i do that ?
I have now an other issue, when i checked/unchecked in my TreeView the property IsChecked change in Root for the node and his childrens but visualy only the one i checked/unchecked change

@BionicCode, Nevermind quick check on google it's ok. And for those who have the same question as me
public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }

            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                foreach(CheckableItem children in Childrens)
                {
                    children.IsChecked = value;
                }
            }
        }

And that was the response to the end of my comment :)

Exactly,n0ow the binding knows when to update the target. See INotifyPropertyChanged for a better implementation that doesn't need the property name as explicit argument.  Check the event invocator implementation in particular.

The TreeView is empty due to your semantic mistake which causes the TreeView.ItemsSource binding to fail.
This is a field:
public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Root;

This is a property:
public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Root { get; set; }

You are basically initializing a public field using a field initializer:
public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Root 
  = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();

However, in WPF you can only bind to public properties and not to fields.
The correct definition must be:
public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Root { get; }
  = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();

